# Is one allowed to make a shaimos "slot"?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

If a shul has shaimos that need to be buried, do they need to dig a new pit each time or can they use an existing pit?

In front of a shul that I saw years ago, they had built a pit, buried some shaimos, covered up most of the pit, but left a small section uncovered. On top of that, they placed a box with a slot. Thus, whenever they want to bury shaimos, they place them in the slot and the shaimos fall into the pit.

Is this technique permitted?

Comment: My gut reaction is "no". However, since I don't have a source and AFAIK, I'm not a gadol, I'm not making that an answer.

Comment: See my answer here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44000/are-you-allowed-to-extract-buried-shemos it seems that it is fine

Comment: @sam I recommend that you move your comment, including the link to an answer, and extract the relevant part of that other answer, to here. My question doesn't seem like a dupe, but your answer to that would apply here, anyway. BTW, I'm not that familiar w/ the Cairo Genizah. Is that above ground?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt "I'm not a gadol" - Well you ARE a Cohen, but we all know you're not the Cohen Gadol ;-) Maybe one day, you will be ... soon. Duchan well for all your fellow Bostonians & the rest of us Monday & Tuesday.

Comment: I will, b'ezrat Hashem.

Comment: @DanF - Just saw this.  The Genizah in Cairo is/was(?) basically a slot in a wall in the side of a crawlspace/storage area on the 2nd floor of the Ben Ezra Synagogue.  Not in the ground at all.  Books got stuffed into that slot for centuries.  I think it was supposed to be emptied regularly and the contents buried, but that never happened, lucky for us!